# Success Test Hanging the Jenkin Build

Tags: node.js, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, supertest

I am new to Jenkin with Supertest and Mocha. I am running a test script and build a script in Jenkin. My test is Success but the Build is hanging up.

Test Script of supertest npm:

```
var request = require('supertest');
var app = require('../index.js');
describe('GET /', function() {
    it('Respond with hello world', function(done) {
        //navigate to root and check the the response is "hello world"
        request(app).get('/').expect({
            status : true,
            message : 'hello world'
        }, done);
    });
});
```

Here is the Screenshot of Jenkin Log:

[Jenkin Log Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS7g7.png)

Could anybody help?

Comment: Is this a part of a bigger Jenkins pipeline?  If so, it might be helpful to post the entire pipeline source, and/or screen shots of your job configuration. Help us see the bigger picture.  I'm not a Mocha, supertest, or even NPM expert, but pipelines can be pretty complicated in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Mocha 4 requires the `--exit` flag in order to terminate after your test. Or, you must configure your app to clean up after itself.

In the Test Script I write `./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./test/test.js` instead of `./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./test/test.js --exit`